# Call function outside inner object with same name?

Tags: scala

When I have a function inside the object with a different name than the function outside, the program works.
Ex:

```
scala> trait Dog {
     | def tag = 123
     | object Cat {
     | def tag2 = tag}
     | }
defined trait Dog

scala> object Foo extends Dog
defined module Foo

scala> Foo.tag
res0: Int = 123

scala> Foo.Cat.tag2
res1: Int = 123
```

However, naming both functions the same name breaks. Can I call the outside function *tag* with the function inside the object *tag*? Thanks.

Ex.

```
trait Dog {
         | def tag = 123
         | object Cat {
         | def tag = tag}
         | } //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give an alternate name for `this` for the outer class:

```
trait Dog { fido =>
  def tag = 123
  object Cat { def tag = fido.tag }
}
```